# Bread dough gluten not fully developed before hitting desired dough temperature

Tags: bread, kneading

I have already made the dough as cold as possible before kneading like freezing the dry ingredients and chilling the biga. If I use my planetary mixer, I can freeze the dough hook, but the new spiral mixer that I am using now has a non-removable hook.

Comment: Why are you freezing anything?

Comment: I live in the Equatorial climate.

Comment: If you want to develop the gluten you could just do a refrigerated autolyse. Then your dough will require minimal mixing when you introduce the biga.

Comment: A "biga" is a small dough-based fermentation starter - https://leitesculinaria.com/79243/recipes-biga.html (for those who didn't know, me included).